# Is .bak file is too big?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-express

I am trying to restore a 12g .bak file to a local location and getting an error saying I cant do anything over around 4g. Is there anyway to increase the size of the location?

I have done some reading and from what I have seen you cant increase the size of the location, only the size of the .bak file. The situation is not one where I can change the size of the .bak file.

Thanks for having a look, any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you restoring this .bak file to a SQL Express instance?

Comment: Please define "local location" and "size of location."

Comment: I am restoring to an express instance and the error I get is:


System.Data.SqlClient.SqlError: CREATE DATABASE or ALTER DATABASE failed because the resulting cumulative database size would exceed your licensed limit of 4096 MB per database. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)

Comment: That is because Express version of 2008 has limitation 4 GB on database size. You can try Express 2008R2 or 2012. They have limitation 10 GB.

Comment: @lgor -- But is .Bak file size is 12gb

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're using SQL Server Express, which has database file size limited to 10GB (4GB for SQL Server 2008 Express or earlier). See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1169634/limitations-of-sql-server-express) for exhaustive discussion and pointers.