# Backend or database system for small business application

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, database, networking

I'm coding a program for a small business. The application's going to be used for store-keeping and the ordering of parts for a mechanical shop. I need some type of backend to store orders, article numbers & prices, customers and so on (obviously). Right now I'm using a local MySQL server and running queries directly from the code. This is not ideal because of the risk of a system meltdown or similar. I've thought about running a local MySQL server - with a scheduled backup on a remote host, but I'm hoping there's a better solution. For previous applications I've written a PHP wrapper, and used a web hotel to host the MySQL server - Which isn't ideal either for security reasons. I suppose I should mention the application's written with windows forms in the VS .net environment(in C#). My question's this: How do I set up a MySQL server (or other type of database system) on a remote host - that I can run queries on and then return the result back to the application? Preferably I wouldn't want to handle the MySQL server myself but outsource it.  I don't mind renting a server from some host - if it will spare me the hassle of setting up a local server machine to run separately. Are there any solutions that you can rent for this purpose? I'm sure there must be tons of information about this on the interwebs but I can't find anything. I would be very thankful if anyone could give me some pointers!

Comment: Hello please see [What topics can I ask about here"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Your question is [primarily opinion-based](http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions). Please post specific code that you are having trouble with.

Comment: Your setup seems fine to me - what's the problem with running queries from code? Query the local MySQL server from C# using queries you've written and you shouldn't have issues with users crashing things.

Comment: if you really want to switch, SQLExpress would work as well as MySQL, and it's free, with some limitations it doesn't sound like you need to worry about: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1169641/264607

Comment: Have you considered Azure? http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/services/data-management/

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Your question is off topic and highly subjective.  Please read [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: What you describe is a two tier application.  Direct access to SQL from the client means direct access to SQL and adds to attack surface.  Microsoft has WCF for three tier applications.   If your app is crashing the system then you are the dimwit not the user.  Voting to close based on opinion based and unprofessional language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way you could do this is rent a cheap VPS and host mysql in there. I have been using DigitalOcean, and it is pretty good. For your needs a $5 per month VPS would be enough.

Or you could use Azure. http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/services/data-management/