# SQL Server 2008 error - cannot allocate space for object

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I'm using SQL Server 2008 Express.

The properties of my database say the DB size is 4GB.

My DB has 2 main tables, each with about 2GB.

I'm getting the following Error when I try to insert a new record:

> [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]
>   Could not allocate space for object 'dbo.Futures_Tick'.'IX_Futures_Tick' in database 'Prices_Live' because the 'PRIMARY' filegroup is full. Create disk space by deleting unneeded files, dropping objects in the filegroup, adding additional files to the filegroup, or setting autogrowth on for existing files in the filegroup.

I'm not sure what to do. I don't see how to free up space in the primary filegroup as the error message is telling me (I'm not even sure what the primary filegroup is).

I'm a little new to DB admin things... I just know the basic SQL commands (Insert, Update, Delete).

help??

Comment: 4GB is the maximum database size for SQL Server 2008 Express. 2008 R2 or 2012 allow 10GB.

Comment: The SQL Server **Express** editions have a size limit - for the **2008** version, it's 4 GB. You cannot go beyond that for a single database - no trick, no workaround, no hack to do so ....

Comment: Limitations of 2008 Express is 4GB the rest of it can be found here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1169634/limitations-of-sql-server-express

Comment: i'm willing to delete some old data to free up some space...if i just delete 6 months worth of records....will that do the trick?  do i need to do anything to reduce the index size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty sure SQL Server 2008 Express is limited to max 4 GB databases. You need to upgrade to 2008R2 or later to overcome it. As 2012 is the most recent that should be the best option unless you have legacy code.

Find it here: [2012 Express Edition](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/editions/2012-editions/express.aspx). And here is the [supported upgrade paths](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143393.aspx).

As @marc_s pointed out in a comment, this version is still limited to 10 GB, so you might want to look into the the paid version if you demand more.

Comment: That just ups the limit to 10 GB. One could also upgrade to a **full** edition (not **Express**) to really get around it for good!

Comment: @marc_s Indeed, but there's a price difference, no? :)

Comment: can i upgrade from 2008 Express to 2012 Express ??

Comment: @user1991508 Yes, but you might have to install a required service pack update (SP2) first. You can find all the information you need here: [Supported Version and Edition Upgrades](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143393.aspx)