# SQL Server Express number of small databases

Tags: sql-server, database, limit, sql-server-express

Having possibly several thousands customers I want to create one DB for each client where I will hold a small sized number of tables and records (from 5000 to less than 100,000 records per DB).

Is there a limitation with SQL Server 2012 or 2014 Express with regard to the maximum number of DBs?

Will this affect the overall performance of the server?

Comment: The maximum number or databases is `32767` and the Maximum size of a database is 10GB for both SQL Server 2012 and 2014, [`Maximum Capacity Specifications for SQL Server`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432%28v=sql.110%29.aspx)

Comment: This may be of interest: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1169634/limitations-of-sql-server-express

Comment: It is technically possible to use Express but you might not be able to get adequate performance with many concurrent clients if the database is used heavily.  Performance may be adequate with fewer concurrent clients and/or the queries are trivial.