# How do I restore a database from SQL Server 2005 to SQL Server 2014 Express?

Tags: sql-server-2014-express

I've backed up a SQL Server 2005 database to a file. When I try to restore it to a SQL Server 2014 Express instance using Management Studio, the source database dropdown does not populate and no restore plans appear. Is this telling me I cannot restore a 2005 db to a 2014 instance? Or is there a way to backup/restore between the two instances?

UPDATE: restoring in a 2008 server, then attempting to restore the back up from that to a 2014 instance, results in the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

One possible cause may be the one or more [limitations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1169634/limitations-of-sql-server-express) of the `Express Editions`. You do not mention SQL Server 2005 or 2008 edition, but I assume is not Express.

Several possible causes are mentioned [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/33870/restore-database-from-backup-file-of-different-version-edition).

If possible, I would try to restore it on a non-Express instance of the same version or higher that the source's version, to rule out edition problems.