# Limitations of using SQL Server Express with TFS 2015 RTM

Tags: tfs, sql-server-express, tfs-2015

Have anyone installed TFS 2015 RTM with SQL Server Express instead of SQL Server 2012? What are limitations and drawbacks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The recommended version of SQL Server for TFS 2015 are **SQL Server 2014** or **SQL Server 2012 (minimum SP1)**. TFS supports Express, Standard, and Enterprise editions of SQL server. The Express edition is only recommended for evaluation purposes, personal use, or for very small teams. We recommend Standard or Enterprise for all other scenarios. See [TFS requirements and compatibility](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vs/alm/tfs/administer/requirements).

You can use the basic configuration of Team Foundation Server, which comes with the required version of SQL Server Express. Check [Limitations of SQL Server Express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1169634/limitations-of-sql-server-express) (stackoverflow post).

Comment: Thanks. I want to use TFS only for version control. In that case, can i use SQL server express? its only for 5 -7 member team?