# What are the professional commercial ethics for using Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Express with Microsoft Visual Web Developer 2010 Express?

Tags: sql-server-2008

What about its commercial use in terms of GPL license?

Comment: Check here :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1169634/limitations-of-sql-server-express

Comment: @TheGameiswar, I am aware of the limitations, just wanted to know the commercial limitations?

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/39b04633-0a09-4d8f-b679-33effe154cdc/sql-server-express-eula?forum=sqlexpress